# android LoaderCallbacks's onLoadFinished does not throw NullPointerException

Tags: android, loader

I saw a strange problem, in LoaderCallbacks' onLoadFinished() I called a method on a null pointer, but I didn't get any exception, and the app quit directly. It took me a lots of time to debug. Did any one saw this already?

```
public class  ForecastFragment extends Fragment
                               implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
   {  
    //...
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
       //here, by accident mForecastAdapter is null, but I get 0 exception, the app quits
        mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {

        mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where creating `mForecastAdapter` object?

Comment: Also, just add a logging method to check if onLoadFinished is getting called at all.
Because if it is getting called, then there should be definitely a null pointer exception.

Comment: mForecastAdapter has not been created, it is null. onLoadFinished is called, I set a breakpoint there, execution stopped at this breakpoint.